# $\pi_1$ representation and de Rham

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $W$ be a smooth/topology manifold(possibly with boundary), such that $\pi_1(W)$ has only trivial representation on $SU(2)$.

**Q** Can we say that $H^1(W;\mathbb R)=0$

Comment: Hint: $H^1(W;\mathbb R)\cong Hom(\pi_1(W),\mathbb R)$